# Cropped Text on TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image: Screenshot of App]
(iOS 6.1.6, iPod Touch 4th Gen, Xcode 7)
Using the default "Subtitle" format for a TableViewController, I'm getting data that looks like this.  Scrolling will sometimes refresh so it shows correctly, but not always.  I've tried widening the labels in the prototype cell, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Creating Cell");
    static NSString *tableID = @"locationOverviewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableID];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = ((PullLocation *)WarehouseLocations[indexPath.row]).WarehouseLocation;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Items To Pull",(int)((PullLocation *)WarehouseLocations[indexPath.row]).NumItemsToPull];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Make sure if you haven't got `category` for `NSString` which overrides `stringWithFormat` method. Or another similar argument: make sure if you haven't got `category` for `UILabel` which overrides `text` method

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to developing for iOS, but I'm not setting `category` anywhere in my code, and I don't see that property anywhere in the Storyboard.  The `NSString` value is created in the code I originally shared, based on data downloaded from our server.